# Return value from function within a class using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, multiprocessing, return-value

I have following piece of codes, which I want to run through multiprocessing, I wonder how can I get return values after parallel processing is finished. I prefer not to make any change to **getdata function**.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class Calculation(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.A, self.B, self.C= a, b, c
        
    def getdata(self):
        self.Product = self.A * self.B
        self.Subtract = self.C - self.B
        self.Addition = self.A + self.B + self.C
        return self.Product, self.Subtract, self.Addition
    

def foo():
    EXTERNAL_C=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 20, 40]
    c = [Calculation(a=4, b=5, c=n) for n in EXTERNAL_C]
    return c
    
K = []
for M in foo():
    p = Process(target=M.getdata)
    p.start()
    K.append(p)
for process in K:
    process.join()
print(K)
```

Output:

```
[<Process(Process-8, stopped[1])>, <Process(Process-9, stopped[1])>, <Process(Process-10, stopped[1])>, <Process(Process-11, stopped[1])>, <Process(Process-12, stopped[1])>, <Process(Process-13, stopped[1])>, <Process(Process-14, stopped[1])>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Calculation` objects you create in your main process are copied into the spawned process, so there is [no way to extract their state](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) or get the return value of `getdata` without doing something explicit.

You could use a `multiprocessing.Queue` to store your results like so

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


class Calculation(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.A, self.B, self.C = a, b, c

    def getdata(self, id, queue):
        self.Product = self.A * self.B
        self.Subtract = self.C - self.B
        self.Addition = self.A + self.B + self.C
        queue.put(
            {
                "id": id,
                "Product": self.Product,
                "Subtract": self.Subtract,
                "Addition": self.Addition,
            }
        )


def foo():
    EXTERNAL_C = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 20, 40]
    c = [Calculation(a=4, b=5, c=n) for n in EXTERNAL_C]
    return c


K = []
f = foo()
queue = Queue()
for id, M in enumerate(f):
    p = Process(target=M.getdata, args=(id, queue))
    p.start()
    K.append(p)
for process in K:
    process.join()

results = [queue.get() for i in range(len(f))]
print(results)
```